# What is the advantage of using pointers in C?

Tags: c, pointers

Why do we use pointers in C Programming?

In general pointers are able to access the address where the int/float/char etc... is stored. 
Are there any other uses?

Comment: Well, isn't that the point (pun not intended)? To be able to reference something stored somewhere else.

Comment: try to implement a linked list in C without pointers and then come back and ask the same question.

Comment: @bolov Or a plain string.

Comment: in short: dynamic arrays with run-time size

Comment: Do some research before asking. Google is your friend. If you ask it,you will get the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you try to achieve:

1. you can change the value of a variable inside a function
2. you can pass a struct to a function without having to copy all its fields - think of a function that receives a struct.
3. you can point to a specific variable/struct and point to it from other structs

and many other advantages (advantages is purpose dependant and it depends on whats your program is doing).

Pointers are quite basic C and there is a lot of material online you should get yourself familiar with them and the advantages will pop up themselves.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that pointers are used to bodge into C some vital features which are missing from the original language: arrays, strings, & writeable function parameters. They can also be used to optimize a program to run faster or use less memory that it would otherwise.  A few tasks these days, such as programming microcontrollers, still need this.